# Network request made by a website is not showing in Chrome DevTools nor Fiddler

Tags: google-chrome, http, web, request

This situation cannot be easily reproduced because the [website](https://www.csgoroll.com/en/withdraw/csgo/all) requires login through Steam.

The webpage shows a list of items that can be purchased. Whenever a new item is listed, it will appear at the top of the list of items. However, when checking Chrome DevTools and Fiddler, I cannot find the Request that is made that contains the data of the newly listed items. In fact, there are no requests made at all.

I am not using any filters in Chrome DevTools.

How is this webpage retrieving data from the server, and why are Chrome and Fiddler not picking up on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question contains the answer: [POST request not showing up in Chrome DevTools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67546011/post-request-not-showing-up-in-chrome-devtools?rq=1)

> [jvda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6152606/jvda):
>
> > This is a common source of conufsion when debugging networking requests done from the web. Normally, developers look at these network requests from top down and assume that the lowest one is the most recent request made - therefore assuming that the request must be at the bottom. For 'plain' HTTP this is correct. However, many apps that want to show data in real-time, use WebSockets to communicate with an API.
> >
> > The same thing happens in the Web-version of Whatsapp. Only assets like the actual JavaScript-app, icons etc are loaded using plain HTTP. Then, a WebSocket is opened through which messages are exchanged for example.

I thought this question was irrelevant but I guess it was not. The data is exchanged through WebSockets